# How to send a newly created excel file in response without saving it on hard-disk?

Tags: java, web-services

```
    List<String> headerRow = Arrays.asList("col1", "col2", "col3","col4","col5"); 
    // Creates a xlsx workbook !!
    XSSFWorkbook wb = ExcelHelper.writeToXlsxExcelFile(headerRow,EjbHelper.getAccountEJb().getCustomersByscPartyNumber("9B7W5")); 
    //Creating a file to dump xlsx
    String fileLocation = "d://try.xlsx";
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
    workbook.write(fout);
    //Want to Create a Webservice to send response without saving file to hard-disk 
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object)fout);
    response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + "ResourceInformation.xlsx");
    return response.build();
```

Above code snippet creates a xlsx file and then sends it over response .I want to know is there any way of sending xlsx file directly without creating file on hard-disk?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose easier way is to use `HttpServletResponse` directly:

```
 public void yourMethod(@Context HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    List<String> headerRow = Arrays.asList("col1", "col2", "col3","col4","col5"); 
    Workbook wb = ExcelHelper.writeToXlsxExcelFile(headerRow,EjbHelper.getAccountEJb().getCustomersByscPartyNumber("9B7W5"));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + "ResourceInformation.xlsx");
    wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```